# Elegant way to filter two related lists

Tags: python

I have a simple `for` loop to do. Here's a MWE:

```
a = [0.6767, -0.0386, 0.6767, 0.4621, 0.6052, 0.3906, 0.6052, 0.3906, 0.6052, 0.4621, 0.6052, 0.4621, 0.5337]
b = [3.6212, 1.5415, 3.4871, 1.8889, 3.3709, 2.078, 3.3012, 2.2236, 3.2265, 2.369, 3.1273, 2.522, 3.0076]
low_lim, high_lim = 0.5, 0.7

c, d = [], []
for indx,i in enumerate(a):
    if low_lim <= i <= high_lim:
        c.append(i)
        d.append(b[indx])
```

So what this `for` loop does is basically to check whether an item in `a` is within a certain range and if it is then it stores that element in `c` and the corresponding `b` element (ie: the element with the same index) in `d`.

How can I write the last block of code more elegantly/succinctly?

Comment: I prefer your original to every answer here. Probably faster. Easier to read. Why change this?

Comment: @dawg I like to compress code as much as possible, sometimes at the expense of readability. I like succinct codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip` to pair and unpair the lists:

```
c,d = zip(*[(ia,ib) for (ia, ib) in zip(a,b) if low_lim <= ia <= high_lim])
```

The splat operator `*` is necessary here. It is possible to splat a generator expression, but I have used a list comprehension here for readability.

Comment: Ohh, using it to unpair as well is clever :-)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Thanks! `zip` is its own inverse, so this is pretty common in general. Once you know about it, it's not *so* clever.

Comment: what do the 'ia' and 'ib' here mean? Assuming it's the i from the for loop does it have the same meaning as a[i] and b[i]?

Comment: @Totem Those are just variables. I could have called them `farts` and `nuts` and it would have worked. The only mechanism here is sequence unpacking. There's no relationship to array subscripts, because no subscripts are being used.

Comment: oh I see, I thought this was inside the for loop for some reason, I was getting an error using it like that

Comment: @Gabriel Good catch. It needs the splat operator (see fixed answer).

Answer (score 4):

numpy is your friend here :)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.6767, -0.0386, 0.6767, 0.4621, 0.6052, 0.3906, 0.6052, 0.3906, 0.6052, 0.4621, 0.6052, 0.4621, 0.5337])
b = np.array([3.6212, 1.5415, 3.4871, 1.8889, 3.3709, 2.078, 3.3012, 2.2236, 3.2265, 2.369, 3.1273, 2.522, 3.0076])
low_lim, high_lim = 0.5, 0.7

mask = (low_lim <= a) & (a <= high_lim)

c = a[mask]
d = b[mask]

cd = np.array([a[mask], b[mask]])
#now if you want a one dimensional array, flatten it.
cd = cd.flatten()
```

Comment: Ups, my bad here. Read it wrong. thought you wanted to store the indexes in d. But ofcourse you can use the same mask to assign d = b[mask]. Gonna edit it

Comment: Is there a reason why `mask` can't be written `low_lim <= a <= high_lim`?

Comment: Also, would it be possible to do this by joining `a` and `b` into one array? That might be more useful in some circumstances.

Comment: It will give a error for reasons beyond me, maybe someone else can give a good answer to that.

Comment: That's a reasonable answer.

Comment: Joining them should not be a problem. AB = np.array([a, b]) for example. then AB[0,:] would represent a, and AB[1,:] would be b

Comment: I'll select Marcin's answer since it uses no extra packages and can be written in one line, but this is a great answer too!

Comment: Ok, as long as your list is small that's fine. For huge lists numpy's speed may come in handy. ~100-200x speed increase vs the zipzip method.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Marcin's answer, however, uses indexes. If you need to do this for more than just two arrays, `enumerate(a)` might be more efficient than using `zip(a,b,c,d,..)`:

```
c,d = zip(*((a[i],b[i]) for i, x in enumerate(a) if low_lim <= x <= high_lim))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, j in itertools.izip(a, b):
    if low_lim <= i <= high_lim:
        c.append(i)
        d.append(j)
```

Comment: Zip is its own inverse, so we can do even better.

Answer (score 0):

Using zip to do the exact same thing:

```
c, d = [], []
for a_elem, b_elem in zip(a, b):
    if low_lim <= a_elem <= high_lim:
        c.append(a_elem)
        d.append(b_elem)
```

If it's acceptable to make a list of tuples instead of two lists, then

```
cd = [(a_elem, b_elem)
      for a_elem, b_elem in zip(a,b)
      if low_lim <= a_elem <= high_lim]
```